# How do I format a journal submission to Angewandte Chemie with LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, achemso, biblatex-chem

Normally when my group writes journal papers we use the `achemso` style and package. However, we want to submit a paper to Angewandte Chemie. They don't appear to provide a LaTeX template, but will take PDF submissions. Now, there is the `chem-angew` Biblatex style, which is perfect for our needs, but we can't use the `achemso` style with it, for affiliation typesetting and such. Is there a replacement paper style we could use, either a general one or a package specific to Angewandte?

We aren't married to `chem-angew` if there is a better way to write up submissions to this journal.

Comment: I'm asking this on behalf of my group, so I may have them make accounts and comment on this.

Comment: Do you just want a bibliography style or for the whole thing? Wiley are not keen on LaTeX, but in the past I think I've seen a review copy sent to them using just `article` (very 'physical' group submitting, so Word probably not a popular plan).

Comment: Did you read http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1521-3757/homepage/2001_latex.html ?
It's pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, we know that if accepted we have to redo everything without packages, which seems a little bit insane and we'll have to figure out how to do our citations, but we only have to worry about that if it is accepted.

Comment: @Alex Yes, John did. However, we aren't expecting it to get accepted, so we are going to worry about redoing it afterwards without packages (which we have no idea how to do; You can do citations with no packages? The figures we can at least make with packages, then screenshot....)

Comment: @JosephWright He wants to use achemso for the author-affiliation bits, the abstract formatting, and that sort of thing. But needs his citations formatted for angew, not acs. Didn't you promise me an independent affiliation package at one point, two years ago? ;)

Comment: @Canageek Well, you can use bibtex and at the very end include the `.bbl` file directly and remove all bibtex related packages and commands.

Comment: @Alex I'll look up how to to do that, thanks. However, that means I need another way to use a angew style citations...

Comment: @Canageek You want the `rsc` bundle for the bibliography, which has an `angew` BibTeX style [written by one Joseph Wright :-)]. On the affiliations, I think 'by hand' is the way to go. The stand-alone package is not forgotten, but I'd like a LaTeX3 solution and there are other open questions to solve there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wiley are not particularly keen on LaTeX submissions, and have [quite restrictive guidelines on the use of LaTeX](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/%28ISSN%291521-3757/homepage/2001_latex.html). As such, they ask your to stick to the `article` class and make absolutely minimal changes.

In terms of bibliography, my [`rsc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rsc) includes a style for *Angewandte Chemie* called `angew`. This requires `natbib`, which means you will need at least that package.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Arduengo1991,
  author = {Arduengo, III, Anthony J. and Harlow, Richard L. and Kline, Michael},
  title = {{A} stable crystalline carbene},
  journal = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  year = {1991},
  volume = {113},
  number = {1},
  pages = {361-363},
  doi = {10.1021/ja00001a054},
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{angew}
\begin{document}

\cite{Arduengo1991}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully they will let you get away with that!

For the affiliations, I think 'by hand' is the best option, especially as they ask you not to use additional packages. The idea of a generalisation of the `achemso` mechanism is not forgotten, but would be a LaTeX3 project for me and so almost certainly ruled out by Wiley's requirements.